# How to add a badge count on Apple Watch complications?

Tags: watchkit, watchos

I noticed that the Messages app has a badge icon on the Apple Watch complication, showing how many unread messages.

If I'm making a Watch App, can I pass the unread count (the same number as on the badge count on iPhone) to the watch complication? How to do so?

Thanks.